# Is certificates's hash algorithm really taken to account in XMLDSig?

Tags: java, xml, hash, xml-signature

I has two pkcs12 containers, one of them has sha1 hash algorithm other has sha256.

I'm signing xml with standart way:

```
 String signMethod = "http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256";
 String digestMethod = "http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256";
 if (doc.getFirstChild() != null) {
     doc.getFirstChild().appendChild(sig.getElement());
     Transforms transforms = new Transforms(doc);
     transforms.addTransform("http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature");
     transforms.addTransform("http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315#WithComments");
     sig.addDocument("", transforms, digestMethod);
     sig.addKeyInfo((X509Certificate) cert);
     sig.sign(privateKey);
  }
```

I signed some xml with "sha1 key" but specified in code sha-256 (check signMethod and digestMethod variables) and verification result was OK. Looks like signing and verifying procedures get algorithm names from appropriate xml tags and it sounds good but **what's the point of specifying signature hash algorithm in p12 file if it doesn't make sense**?

The only explanation is creating PKCS7 signature where usually one doesn't specify hash algo and it probably taken from p12.

So, my hypothesis is the following:

In xml signing tag values are important (specified in transforms), p12 hash algo doesn't matter. In pkcs7 or other situations where developer doesn't specify hash algo it taken from p12. Am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not specifying the hash algorithm of the certificate here. That's already specified. You're specifying the hash algorithm used for the signature.

Comment: If I got you correctly you are saying that hash algo in certificate is not for digesting signature but for digesting other things. But what is the purpose of that signature hash algorithm? I intentionally wrote put it in bold because it's quote from .cer file produced from p12.

Comment: The hash algorithm in the certificate describes the certificate's own signature. Not the digital signature you are creating.

Comment: Thanks for clarification. Now I understand it as "algo for cert chain (CA) checking" and most likely it's correct. Just a kind proposal - I accepted your answer but it would be useful for "next generations" to edit answer with explicit change "signature" to "certificate signature". I don't want to change anything as I'm not 100% confident and don't want to "spoil" your answer.